# Write External Storage Permission is always denied

Tags: android, permissions

I'm using Download Manager to Download Image in my android app.

To obtain the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission I'm suing [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) library.

```
        Dexter.withContext(getApplicationContext())
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                    Toast.makeText(LiveTaskActivity.this, "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                    Toast.makeText(LiveTaskActivity.this, "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {

                }
            }).check();
```

But always I get permission "Denied" even I manually accept the permission to grant the permission from the app. I also tried manually implementing the permission request code.

```
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    } else {
        download();
    }
```

Still, I can't get the permission. Here is the Manifest Code:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Here is my buil.gradle(app) code:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.gigg.me.app"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 2
    versionName '1.0.1'
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

**Update Here is my download code

```
    private void startDownload() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Downloading File...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    fileName = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + ".png";
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath(), fileName);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(link))
            .setTitle(fileName)
            .setDescription("Downloading")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file))
            .setMimeType("image/*")
            .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
    download_id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Comment: You do not need that permission as you let the DownloadManager do the download and save and DownloadManager will do without it.

Comment: @blackapps When I tried to directly use this download manager its gave me this error: `neither user nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Can you give me any references for doing this, please?

Comment: Show your download code to begin with. And tell Android version of used device.

Comment: @blackaps [Here's the screenshot of my code](https://prnt.sc/16avck9)

It is working on android 11 but in android 7.1.1 it is giving the error.

Comment: Check you have required permissions before the DownloadManager code block and if not then prompt permission window

Comment: @blackapps I've added code to my post.

Comment: @Akki I also tried this. It does not work in android 7.1.1

Comment: Instead of setDestinationUri use setDestinationInExternalPublicDir. Can you test other Android versions?

Comment: @blackapps Works on android 11, but when I tried on android 7.1.1 it is giving this error: 
`Neither user 10087 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.`

Comment: If your target SDK is >=29 then the “getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()” is deprecated
So, I think you have to replace "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory" with methods suggested here [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)]

Comment: Also, as suggested by @blackapps, you can tryout with "setDestinationInExternalPublicDir".

Comment: @Akki thanks a lot. `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()` this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not available when you target Android 11 (`targetSdkVersion 30`).

You can read more here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: My download manager code works fine on android 11. But when I'm trying on android 7.1.1 it is giving this error:
`Neither user 10087 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.`